What is the value of my Roblox account?
How can I check the real value of the amount of Robux I have in-game?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

there are calculators for that https://sponsorhunter.com/calculators/robux-to-usd-calculator/

According to the Roblox Help section, the current exchange rates in use are:

New Rate. $.0035/R$ (which comes out to $105 USD for 30,000 Robux). This rate applies to all Robux earned on or after March 1, 2017.
Old Rate. $.0025/R$ (which comes out to $75 USD for 30,000 Robux). This rate applies to all Robux earned before March 1, 2017.

So you'll have to know which amount of your Robux was earned before the 1st of March 2017 (if any).
Once you know that, you can calculate the value in USD yourself:

[amount of Robux earned *before* 01-03-2017] x 0.0025 = value 1

[amount of Robux earned after 01-03-2017] x 0.0035 = value 2

value 1 + value 2 = total value of Robux in USD


As A. Bakker points out in the comments, there are online calculators for seeing what your amount of in-game currency is worth in real money, or how much your next Robux purchase will set you back, but most of then seem to use the wrong (old?) exchange rates. Apart from this, they also can't take into account the division mentioned above.
This one, RoMonitorStats.com, however, seems to use the right current (post-1.3.2017) exchange rates, and can convert to different valuta, but remember to take into account their "$5 eCheck Fee" (e.g. using the amount mentioned in the Roblox Help article, 30.000 Robux is $105, but on this site it will show as $100 + $5 eCheck Fee).
